# Because my api, after publishing through the AzureDevops pipeline in flurl methods, the entryPointNotFoundException exception is occurring

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, azure-pipelines, flurl

I have an api in .net framework 4.8 that uses the flurl package to make http calls. Running the api directly through visual studio, or even publishing it, it works correctly, however when generating the build from an azureDevOps pipeline, it builds and generates correctly, but in http calls using flurl this error occurs: System .EntryPointNotFoundException: The entry point was not found.
in System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1.GetEnumerator() in System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) in System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
in Flurl.Http.FlurlRequest.SyncHeaders(IFlurlClient client, IFlurlRequest request)
in Flurl.Http.FlurlRequest.EnsureClient()

I've tried several things, all without success, I hoped that the build from the pipeline would work.

Comment: [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)